# How to update elements passed in slot with Stencil.js?

Tags: angular, stenciljs, stencil-component

I am creating a radio web component with Stencil.js.

Stencil.js code:

```
  <div>
    <slot/>
    <label>
      {this.label} <span/>
    </label>
  </div>
```

I pass an input of type radio. Usage in Angular:

```
<my-radio label="{{fruit}}">
    <input name="fruits" type="radio" id="{{fruit}}">
</my-radio>
```

When I click it the "input" I expect it should change from `<input name="fruits" type="radio" id="banana">` to `<input name="fruits" type="radio" id="banana" checked>` .

But the input never gets the attribut "checked" even though everything is rendered properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior that is independent of Stencil.

[MDN's docs on the radio checked attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#htmlattrdefchecked):

> A Boolean attribute which, if present, indicates that this radio button is the default selected one in the group.

The [MDN docs for checkboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#htmlattrdefchecked) make it more clear:

> A Boolean attribute indicating whether or not this checkbox is checked by default (when the page loads). It does not indicate whether this checkbox is currently checked: if the checkbox’s state is changed, this content attribute does not reflect the change. (Only the HTMLInputElement’s checked IDL attribute is updated.)

You can use the `checked` **property** instead to get the current value:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]').checked;
```

Comment: You are right, the input element is working as designed. To make it work I had to make a parent component "my-radio-group". Then similar like you recommend I had to get all "my-radio" and handle the toggle in there.